# $\frac{1}{n - 1} E \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 \right]$ to $\frac{1}{n - 1} E \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2 - n \bar{Y}\right]$?

Tags: variance, unbiased-estimator

I have that $S^2 = \dfrac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2$, and I am trying to show that $S^2$ is an unbiased estimator. I get the following:

$$E[S^2] = E \left[ \dfrac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 \right] = \dfrac{1}{n - 1} E\left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 \right] = \dfrac{1}{n - 1} E\left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i^2 - 2Y_i \bar{Y} + \bar{Y}^2) \right]$$

The examples I see go straight from $ \dfrac{1}{n - 1} E \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 \right]$ to $ \dfrac{1}{n - 1} E \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2 - n \bar{Y}\right]$ without explanation. How do we get $\dfrac{1}{n - 1} E \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 \right]$ to $ \dfrac{1}{n - 1} E \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2 - n \bar{Y}\right]$? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equalities are incorrect, you should have $\sum Y_i^2 - n\bar{Y}^2$ on the RHS

First focus on the sum:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i^2 - \bar{Y}^2) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} [Y_i^2 - 2Y_i \bar{Y} + (\bar{Y})^2 ]\\ 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2 - 2 \bar{Y} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i + (\bar{Y})^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n}1 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2 - 2n(\bar{Y})^2 + n(\bar{Y})^2\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2 - n(\bar{Y})^2
\end{aligned}
$$
the first equality follows by the quadratic formula $(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$, the second simply distributes the sum and uses the fact that the mean is same for all $i$. The third equality uses $\sum Y_i = n\bar{Y}$.

The rest of the proof is simply linearity of expectations